# Setproperty in SOAPUI using Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a property name - "auth-token" on a TestSuite level. There is a TestStep API request which gives me a Authentication-Token, I capture the Authentication-Token using below:

```
def setAuth = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["CheckAvailability"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders["authentication-token"]
```

NextStep -- I want to use this "setAuth "[authentication-token] as header for another TestStep

When i call the below:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps("Book").setPropertyValue("auth-token",setAuth.toString())
```

It gives me an Error:

> "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.testSteps() is
>   applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Book]
>   Possible solutions: getTestSteps() error at line: 3"

Can someone please assist?

Comment: What is the significance of mentioning `"auth-token" on a Testsuite level`

Comment: All you want is to be able to send the auth token as header to next step?

Comment: mentioning the "auth-token" on a Testsuite level will allow me to use the same authentication token across the Suite level. Yesi want to use the auth token in some other step

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks

Comment: The above error is because of the wrong syntax - it has to be like testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Book"]... and  not testRunner.testCase.testSteps("Book")...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use this "setAuth "[authentication-token] as header for another TestStep you need:
1)create TestCase's property(with name "setAuth") and save header value in this property, like this:

```
def setAuth = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["CheckAvailability"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders["authentication-token"]
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("setAuth", setAuth)
```

2) and then create header in another TestStep, for example header name "setAuth" and set value ${#TestCase#setAuth}